# Javascript - Referencing certain HTML elements inside of a loop

Tags: javascript, css, loops, menu

I'm making a simple Javascript menu that switches between tabs containing mostly HTML forms and text.
To this end, I've used the following code to assign on-click attributes to list elements changing the styling settings of classes:
http://jsfiddle.net/NHKZL/

The problem in this case is that the code tracks menu content  by going through the list of classes to find elements to open/close (container>.class). This works fine when using plain text in each of the tabs but less so when using different content such as php echoes and loops. I assume that this is due to JS considering some of these tags classes.

This is the line of code:

```
var target = document.querySelector('.container>.' + e.target.classList[0]);
```

the part in particular that I am looking for an alternative to is:

> classlist[0]

The person who posted the code pointed out this weakness and suggested using data-* to track the elements that I wish to affect, but I can't seem to figure out how this affects the remainder of the syntax in this particular line. The other half of my solution currently consists of adding data-* attributes to the classes inside of the container class. 
Any other suggestions on how to do this are welcome.

Comment: data-* are attributes like class is. So you should use for example `data-count="5"` to pass a value of 5 for the attribute count. Then on the js side you can use var count = $(selector).data('count'); or var count = $(selector).attr('data-count'); You indeed are adding data-* in the class? What do you mean?

Comment: @LelioFaieta Since the question doesn't have a `jquery` tag, you really should mention getting data attributes in a pure JavaScript way.  I prefer `<element>.getAttribute("data-count"); ` or the new `dataset` API.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: The essence of this question is just making the JS loop find every element with a data tag inside of it. The actual value is irrelevant, as long as I have a method to "mark" the elements to be affected by this loop. Originally it would go through every class and then start adding the click event to things inside of the classes which I wanted to affect. (div class toggle under container in the Fiddle.)

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher you are right. I was more focused on understanding what he referred to when he ways "adding data-* attributes to the classes inside of the container class."

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I've already tried: 
"var target = document.querySelector('.container>.' + e.target.getAttribute("data-count"));"
but it didn't work. Most likely because this doesn't refer to the actual element name the way that "container>.class" would have. It just ends up being a container followed by a random data string.

Comment: @noobequaltotrue I provided you an answer below..

Comment: @Saar Thanks, I will give it a look immediately!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update your fiddle with how to use data-* attributes: http://jsfiddle.net/NHKZL/441/

HTML, added data-index attribute:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="toggle1" data-index="1">One</li>
    <li class="toggle2" data-index="2">Two</li>
    <li class="toggle3" data-index="3">Three</li>
    <li class="toggle4" data-index="4">Four</li>
    <li class="toggle5" data-index="5">Five</li>
</ul>
<div class="container">
    <div class="toggle1" data-index="1">Here are the contents of 1.</div>
    <div class="toggle2" data-index="2">Here are the contents of 2..</div>
    <div class="toggle3" data-index="3">Here are the contents of 3...</div>
    <div class="toggle4" data-index="4">Here are the contents of 4....</div>
    <div class="toggle5" data-index="5">Here are the contents of 5.....</div>
</div>
```

JS, notice in the selector I selected child elements of container with the same data-index number:

```
var menu_elements = document.querySelectorAll('.menu>li'),
    menu_length = menu_elements.length;
for (var i = 0; i < menu_length; i++) {
    menu_elements[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var target = document.querySelector('.container> [data-index="' + e.target.getAttribute("data-index")+'"]'); // clicked element
        Array.prototype.filter.call(target.parentNode.children, function (siblings) {
            siblings.style.display = 'none'; // hide sibling elements
        });
        target.style.display = 'block'; // show clicked element
    });
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot. This was the syntax I couldn't seem to find. Also, on a side note, what is the {debugger tag for?

Comment: I removed the `debugger;`, it is basically a break-point in the code if you want to check something. I always add it when I check a fiddle and then remove it in the end